# How can I add an empty row in a for loop based on a previous for loop?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to make a comparison report that displays sales for two time periods, in this scenario i've selected 1-31 October and 1-30th November. I am loading the data from the same Json file but as two seperate queries, the first uses the October period and the second uses the November period.

**This is the code I have currently:**

```
// October 1-31
<div class="col-6" *ngFor="let periods of reportData">
    <div *ngFor="let reportVal of periods.groupedTransactions">
        <div class="row" *ngIf="reportData.length > 0">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h6>Customer: {{reportVal.name}}</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <h6>Total Sales: {{reportVal.totalSales | number}}</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
// November 1-30
<div class="col-6" *ngFor="let comPeriods of comReportData">
    <div *ngFor="let reportVal of comPeriods.groupedTransactions">
        <div class="row" *ngIf="comReportData.length > 0">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h6>Customer: {{reportVal.name}}</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <h6>Total Sales: {{reportVal.totalSales | number}}</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Is there a way to add a function that will add an empty row in the November if there is no sales from that customer? I want to have all the Customers vertically aligned.

Because the periods for loop is based on the selected dates, putting the columns in the same loop will only get data from one date.

If anyone can help me out or tell me where to look to solve this it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of your approach, your primary loop should be over the set of customers that are in all periods.

I would create a de-normalised view model that combines customers and reports. Your final view model structure would probably look something like this in spirit:

```
periods: [
  {
    name: 'October 2019'
    customers: [
      {
        name: 'John',
        totalSales: 100
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
]
```

The complexity is in how you build it. Something like

```
periods.forEach(period => {
  const periodViewModel = {};
  this.viewModel.periods.push(periodViewModel);

  customers.forEach(customer => {
    const customerViewModel = {
      name: customer.name,
      totalSales: this.getSales(customer, period)
    };

    periodViewModel.customers.push(customerViewModel);
  });
});
```

Where `this.getSales(customer, period)` is some way of getting the sales data for a given customer and period - probably a local variable. You may want to optimise your sales data for retrieval by customer / period, depending on how many periods / customers you have.

And then it becomes pretty trivial to bind this view model to your HTML. Let your typescript take care of the complicated model, and keep your UI simple.

Comment: So right now i'm pulling the data from a Json file that holds all the transactions and customer name, so everything is combined into the same file. It pulls in all customers and transactions within the period. Should I somehow pull in customers and then the two transaction periods? Sorry if i'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: It should be fairly simple to transform that block of json into a structure that you want. As you process the json, pull out the relevant data. I would store active customers in a `Map<Customer>` to get your set of customers. My example assumes an existing array of customers and periods, but that doesn't change the principle of the answer. Could you create a stackblitz (with anonymised or simplified data) to show me what you have so far.

Comment: Here's the stackblitz with the reports section. I wan't able to get the json file to pull data in the demo but the two json periods are included in the assets folder. Hopefully you might be able to spot what I need to change to align the periods.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/reports-demo-1?file=assets%2Ftransactions.json

Comment: That's a big haystack for a small needle! Can you reproduce the problem with minimal code and static models instead of json data?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps... If this is not the expected result you want to display, Please share the json  format.

**customer.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
<h2>Customer Sales</h2>
<p>The below table is listing monthly sales of the customer in the year 2019 </p>  
<div *ngFor="let report of reportData">
    <h5>Month: {{report.month}}</h5>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Customer</th>
                <th>Total Sales</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let sales of report.groupedTransactions">
                <td>{{sales.name}}</td>
                <td>{{sales.totalSales}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table> 
</div>
```

**customer.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {


this.reportData = [
  {
    month: 'October',
    groupedTransactions: [
      {
        name: 'John',
        totalSales: 100
      },
      {
        name: 'Rita',
        totalSales: 80
      },
      {
        name: 'Edward',
        totalSales: 70
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    month: 'November',
    groupedTransactions: [
      {
        name: 'John',
        totalSales: 90
      },
      {
        name: 'Rita',
        totalSales: null
      },
      {
        name: 'Edward',
        totalSales: 120
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

}

}
    }

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to align the two periods. For example adding an entry with the name of the missing customer and a total sales of 0.I don't know how your json likes like but maybe you should also assume that the order of the customers might not be the same for different periods. Sorting both by name might be a solution.

You could come up with something like this to align both periods:

```
interface CustomerReport {
  name: string;
  totalSales: number;
}

alignPeriods(firstPeriod: CustomerReport[], secondPeriod: CustomerReport[]) {
    const alignedFirstPeriod: CustomerReport[] = Object.assign([], firstPeriod);
    const alignedSecondPeriod: CustomerReport[] = [];

    firstPeriod.forEach(customer => {
      const secondCustomer = secondPeriod.find(secCustomer => secCustomer.name === customer.name);
      if (!secondCustomer) {
        alignedSecondPeriod.push({name: customer.name, totalSales: 0});
      } else {
        alignedSecondPeriod.push(secondCustomer);
      }
    });

    secondPeriod.forEach(customer => {
      const firstCustomer = firstPeriod.find(fstCustomer => fstCustomer.name === customer.name);
      if (!firstCustomer) {
        alignedFirstPeriod.push({name: customer.name, totalSales: 0});
        alignedSecondPeriod.push(customer);
      }
    });

    const alignedCustomers = [alignedFirstPeriod, alignedSecondPeriod];
    return alignedCustomers;
  }
```

This function makes sure both arrays are in the same order and adds a new entry with totalSales:0 for all customers which are not in the other period. This assumes the names of your customers are unique ids.

Now you can loop over both aligned arrays in your template.

This will work but it is not a clean solution, you should consider changing your data model like Kurt Hamilton mentioned in his answer.